# Railties gem compatibly issue - sorry I am new to Rails and Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, bundler

when pushing to Heroku I get the following bundler error

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
 Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
In Gemfile:
            rails (= 3.2.1) ruby depends on
             railties (= 3.2.1) ruby
               jquery-rails (= 2.0.0) ruby depends on
                  railties (3.2.6)
```

Comment: Do you have any lines for `railties` in your `Gemfile`?

Comment: remove the jquery-rails version dependency from Gemfile, or update it to be compatible with rails 3.2.1

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, so I looked up the jquery-rails gem and saw that it has been updated to version 2.0.2.  I updated my Gemfile to that version and ran bundle install again and everything worked.  Commit your Gemfile of course, so that the update gets pushed to Heroku as well.